# Joining tables where json field id corresponds to column in other table

Tags: json, postgresql

I have two tables, the first, called orders, stores a json[] data type that looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (id SERIAL, items: json[], price: REAL);

INSERT INTO orders (items, price) VALUES ('[{"itemId":1,"addons":["ice","cream"]},{"itemId":2,"addons":["mayo","peppers"]}]',12.4);
```

And the other, called items, stores the itemId corresponding to the "itemId" in the json data type:

```
CREATE TABLE items(id SERIAL, name TEXT, price REAL);

INSERT INTO items(name,price) VALUES ('Chicken Bowl', 8.99);
```

I want to join the tables in such a way to return the text value from the items table which corresponds to the itemId in the orders table, rather than the id itself, for example returning 'Chicken Bowl' for "itemId" rather than 1

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using JSON this way in your schema?

Comment: I figured it was the best way to store multiple food items per order since there's theoretically no upper limit to the number of food items there could be in each

Comment: I can possibly suggest an alternative schema which does not use JSON.  I would recommend using JSON only if you plan to use it in your application layer.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: If you could share the alternative schema that would be great

Comment: `json[]` almost never makes sense. It would be much better to store a real json array inside a `jsonb` column

Comment: @KaushikNayak Ideally JSON where the id number is replaced by the item name

Answer (score 0):

Although the schema is not really good for this type of queries, here is one of way of doing it:

```sql
SELECT o.id, i.name
FROM orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL unnest(o.items) AS u ON (true)
    INNER JOIN items AS i ON ((u->>'itemId')::int = i.id)
;
```

...produces (according to given test data):

```
 id |     name     
----+--------------
  1 | Chicken Bowl
(1 row)
```

If you want to aggregate all items to each order, use the following:

```sql
SELECT o.id AS order, array_agg(i.name) AS items
FROM orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL unnest(o.items) AS u ON (true)
    INNER JOIN items AS i ON ((u->>'itemId')::int = i.id)
GROUP BY 1;
```

...producing:

```
 order |      items       
-------+------------------
     1 | {"Chicken Bowl"}
(1 row)
```